# Make ul items list and wrap to its parent

Tags: html, css

So I have a menu that I generate from a php query the output looks like:

```css
#ultra-menu {
  width: 92%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
  top: 82px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
#ultra-menu h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e4810b;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#ultra-menu a {
  color: #28281e;
}
#ultra-menu a:hover {
  color: #e4810b;
}
#ultra-menu ul {
  margin: 7px;
  float: left;
}
.um-cat {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
}
#um-fresh {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="ultra-menu" class="site-sub-navigation align-center" role="navigation">
  <div id="um-fresh" class="um-cat">
    <h3><b>Freshwater</b></h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/books-media/"><b>Books &amp; Media</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-accessories/"><b>Fishing Accessories</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/fishing-nets/">Fishing Nets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/fishing-tools-accessories/">Fishing Tools &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/rod-accessories/">Rod Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/smokers-flasks/">Smokers &amp; Flasks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/sunglasses/">Sunglasses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wader-accessories/">Wader Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wader-repair/">Wader Repair</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wading-staffs/">Wading Staffs</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-clothing/"><b>Fishing Clothing</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/coats-jackets/">Coats &amp; Jackets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/gloves/">Gloves</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/hats-caps/">Hats &amp; Caps</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/freshwater-fishing-clothing-jackets/">Jackets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/jumpers-fleeces/">Jumpers &amp; Fleeces</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/life-jackets/">Life jackets &amp; Collars</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/socks/">Socks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/thermals-base-layers/">Thermals &amp; Base Layers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/trousers-shorts/">Trousers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/vests-waistcoats/">Vests &amp; Waistcoats</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/waders-boots/">Waders &amp; Boots</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/wading-jackets/">Wading Jackets</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-equipment/"><b>Fishing Equipment</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/backing-nylon-accessories/">Backing, Nylon &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-lines/">Fly Lines</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-reels/">Fly Reels</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-rods/">Fly Rods</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/leaders-tippets/">Leaders &amp; Tippets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/freshwater-fishing-equipment-rod-accessories/">Rod Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/spools/">Spools</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/flies-fly-tying/"><b>Flies &amp; Fly Tying</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/gifts-miscellaneous/"><b>Gifts &amp; Miscellaneous</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/luggage-storage/"><b>Luggage &amp; Storage</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/spinning/"><b>Spinning</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/braid-line/">Braid &amp; Line</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinners/">Spinners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-accessories/">Spinning Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-reels/">Spinning Reels</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-rods/">Spinning Rods</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

What I am trying to do here is make them list from left to right wrap its container like the image:

[image]

So that instead of having whitespace under each `<ul>` I would like the other `<ul>` to fit underneath.

I know this is possible with flex box's but for compatibility I don't want them on my site.

Comment: take a look at this library http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @knets Really looking for a CSS solution to this issue. As the HTML is not hardcoded and is generated from a php loop would be great to figure out a css alternative perhaps using CSS tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css only you could use `column-count` on your parent element in your case #um-fresh.

Then on your children you want to act masonry like you would use `display: inline-block;`

Though it technically has the same support as Flex-box's I would say it's an easier solution than flex box.

[Flex Box Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

[Column Count Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count)

A safer conduct might be to use [JSMasonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) because of the lack of IE9 and 8 support.

Though saying that you could put in a conditional statement for `<IE9` and activate jsMasonry so you are not polluting your site with additional js. That way you have a CSS only version and then when the user is on an older browser they get the js masonry so that it still looks right.

Also if you are using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you could detect if column-count is working and if not then run jsMasonary.

---

so your css for Column Count would be like:

```css
#ultra-menu {
  width: 92%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
  top: 82px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
#ultra-menu h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e4810b;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#ultra-menu a {
  color: #28281e;
}
#ultra-menu a:hover {
  color: #e4810b;
}
#ultra-menu ul {
  margin: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.um-cat {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
}
#um-fresh {
  display: block;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

```html
<nav id="ultra-menu" class="site-sub-navigation align-center" role="navigation">
  <div id="um-fresh" class="um-cat">
    <h3><b>Freshwater</b></h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/books-media/"><b>Books &amp; Media</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-accessories/"><b>Fishing Accessories</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/fishing-nets/">Fishing Nets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/fishing-tools-accessories/">Fishing Tools &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/rod-accessories/">Rod Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/smokers-flasks/">Smokers &amp; Flasks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/sunglasses/">Sunglasses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wader-accessories/">Wader Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wader-repair/">Wader Repair</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-accessories/wading-staffs/">Wading Staffs</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-clothing/"><b>Fishing Clothing</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/coats-jackets/">Coats &amp; Jackets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/gloves/">Gloves</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/hats-caps/">Hats &amp; Caps</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/freshwater-fishing-clothing-jackets/">Jackets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/jumpers-fleeces/">Jumpers &amp; Fleeces</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/life-jackets/">Life jackets &amp; Collars</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/socks/">Socks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/thermals-base-layers/">Thermals &amp; Base Layers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/trousers-shorts/">Trousers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/vests-waistcoats/">Vests &amp; Waistcoats</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/waders-boots/">Waders &amp; Boots</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-clothing/wading-jackets/">Wading Jackets</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/fishing-equipment/"><b>Fishing Equipment</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/backing-nylon-accessories/">Backing, Nylon &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-lines/">Fly Lines</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-reels/">Fly Reels</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/fly-rods/">Fly Rods</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/leaders-tippets/">Leaders &amp; Tippets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/freshwater-fishing-equipment-rod-accessories/">Rod Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/fishing-equipment/spools/">Spools</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/flies-fly-tying/"><b>Flies &amp; Fly Tying</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/gifts-miscellaneous/"><b>Gifts &amp; Miscellaneous</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/luggage-storage/"><b>Luggage &amp; Storage</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="um-par"><a href="/spinning/"><b>Spinning</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/braid-line/">Braid &amp; Line</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinners/">Spinners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-accessories/">Spinning Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-reels/">Spinning Reels</a>
      </li>
      <li class="um-sub"><a href="/spinning/spinning-rods/">Spinning Rods</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```